# Raspberry Pi vs PC (comparing algorithm speedup)

Tags: parallel-processing, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to solve this question:
if 75% of a code can be distributed over a cluster, and you had one of the options: 40 raspberry pis or 2 pcs each is 4 times the performance of a cluster.
Which option would you pick?

So this is likely to be solved by calculating the speed up of each.
considering Amdahl's law, the max speed up is <= 1/(f+(1-f)/n) where f is the percent of code that can be done in parallel and n is number of processors.

My solution:

Max Raspberry speed up = 1/(0.75 + (1-0.75)/40), that is 1.322

Now if this statement "with each PC having four times the performance of a
Raspberry Pi" means that each PC is equal to 4 raspberry pis then i'd say n = 8.

Thus, S PC max = 1/(0.75 + (1-0.75)/8) = 1.28

I would pick the 40-node raspberry pi over the 2 PCs, but i am not quite sure if i had computed the PC's speed-up correctly. Is it safe to assume that each PC is equivalent to 4 raspberry pis (4 processors)?

Comment: I fixed up the styling a bit.. Don't know why 2 lines are counted as one on this website. As for the content, this is an exam question. I'm currently preparing for a test by solving examples.

Comment: Much better.  But, like I wrote earlier, I am done with exams.